# Could firearms realistically have RFID reader built into them so they could be tracked?

Tags: technology, technological-development, near-future, firearms, dystopia

Firearms on their interior are very lacking in space, and putting an RFID reader on the exterior takes up the space that could be used by attachments like a CornerShot or vertical foregrip. It would also be exposed to the elements and could be damaged if the gun is dropped or slammed into a wall by the user on accident.

In a dystopian setting, implanted RFID tags would be used to track the whereabouts of civilians and to control what they can and can't do. The government could disable the RFID tag in a certain individual preventing them from using their gun.

Comment: I am not certain that I understand why you would want an RFID *reader* built into each firearm instead of a much smaller, much more resilient RFID *tag*. They are very different devices; among other, a simple RFID tag does not require a power source.

Comment: @AlexP In this context, the reader would probably be in the gun and the passive tag attached to the user. The smart gun would need to have a power source anyway, so the radio tag reader and trigger enabler/disabler can be embedded into the weapon.

Comment: @CongenitalOptimist: The question asks about *tracking* firearms. Nothing more than a passive RFID tag is needed for tracking; that is what RFID tags *are for*. And the word "smart" does not appear in the question at all.

Comment: @AlexP After reading the title, I actually came here to say the same as your comment pointed out. The gun as an inventory item should have a tag, not reader. The second paragraph of  the OP question however...

Comment: RFID is simple. Dallas Semiconductor developed what they call their iButton (it wasn't called that when I worked there), which is an RFID chip that's used to gain access to rooms, drawers, etc. Handy little device, and it's principally just an integrated circuit with an antenna. It could easily fit inside a weapon. However, like most people have pointed out, the problem isn't the RFID - it's the electronics and mechanics used to disable the weapon that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Electronic Guns**:

Guns with electrical triggering mechanisms are being developed today like the metalstorm system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Storm) that could be hooked up to standardized ignition system controlled by the government.The government could easily install a chip in such a system so that a police officer could send a signal to disable all civilian guns in the area.  If it is so desired, the existence of this chip could be a secret, or there could be more than one built in, so people who "take out" the restrictor chip only have removed part of the system.

The same thing could cause your gun to ping readers as people came and went from monitored areas. This would give the ID of the individual weapon, and the police could have a more specific system to disable the trigger of just that specific gun. In the event that an officer's gun was taken from him, the weapon could be designed to only fire within a certain radius of a (watch/ring/bracelet) so the gun couldn't be seized from an officer and used against him (as happens in a surprising number of instances). The Feds could still disable police weapons so you wouldn't have local governments or officers getting any ideas.

Electronic guns give a nice scifi feel to your world and a convenient delivery system for this control tech. You would probably want to ban all old guns, but maybe it would be a nice touch in your world for criminals to carry makeshift muskets, smoothbore pistols and blunderbusses, a little like in *Looper*. Crudely modified guns with wiring hanging all over can take the place of the nice, sophisticated triggers of factory-issue weapons.

Answer (score 5):

*Frame Challenge*:

The issue isn't the reader, the issue is disabling (and *conditionally* disabling) the firearm.

## RFID Is Probably Not the Answer

Getting a small enough reader isn't too challenging - right now, for $50, you can get one that's [less than an inch square](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/dlp-design-inc/DLP-RFID2/3770244).  Powering it might be a problem, but the remaining two challenges are the big deal.

1. RFID, as currently implemented, is passive.  The reader provides not only the prompt, but also the field that induces a current in the tag to provide its unique identifier.  This is not modifiable.  So most readers (like lock systems) have a white list of "acceptable identifiers".  Removing someone's access to a building involves removing them from the whitelist.  So if the government wanted to make it so a specific person could no longer use a firearm, they would have to be able to remotely update the firearm's whitelist - at which point, they could just remotely disable it anyway.
2. There's also the problem most authorities currently have with most experimental smart guns, and that the US had with permissions systems on its nuclear arsenal - most of the time, if the users of the weapon need to use it, they don't want it not to work, and if you're introducing a mechanism to the gun that automatically bricks it for unauthorized users, there's the very real risk of it doing it for *authorized* users too.  Let's say your government-sponsored jackbooted thug takes a shot to the hand that punches clean through their embedded microchip.  Not only are they injured, they've abruptly lost any ability to use their weapon, as well, because they *had* to use the hand with the microchip.  Unless the weapon is *very* smart, all that you introduce with a automatic default safety is another point of failure, which makes the gun less useful in the role for which it is designed.

Now, that aside, the authority might be alright with issuing often-faulty guns to its agents, reasoning that agents not being able to use their weapons when they need to is less important than agents not being able to use their weapons when the government doesn't want them to, but that would still require a whitelist on the gun.  And as any security expert can tell you, if you've lost physical security on your secured item (in this case, the gun), assume the hardware can be compromised.

Now, this is different from the question in the title of your post, which suggests that you want to track the gun, which is a much easier proposition.  GPS modules can be very small.

---

Edit: All this assumes you're using actual RFID (as it works in real life) and that the guns aren't particularly smart.  Judge Dredd's guns identify their users just fine, by the simple virtue of not caring much how they do it.  If all you're after is that kind of behaviour, I'd go with the [Lawgiver](https://judgedredd.fandom.com/wiki/Lawgiver) approach.

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of gun safety systems on the market which rely on [biometrics or RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_gun). The problem is making one that could not easily be disabled, at least not without breaking the gun or leaving evidence.

- Would the government "disable the RFID tag" on a citizen or remove the citizen from the list of permitted gun users? The gun downloads the current list of permitted users from a server, and reports to the server if it is held by anyone not on the list.
- Say a citizen has a legal gun, with the legally mandated gun safety device. Then he reports that the safety device has been damaged. The cops will note that, and also when exactly the safety was last known to work. (Scanned at a licensed gun range? It calls the cellphone network every hour?)
- Semiautomatic handguns consist of the barrel, slide, and grip assemblies. The RFID safety could be part of the slide or grip. Can a criminal 3D-print a replacement part without the safety? The grip has the most space for such a gadget, but it is also least stressed -- easy to print.
- *Questioning the frame:* Your dystopian government would have to ban readerless guns. If they can pull that off, why not ban all civilian handguns?
- *Questioning the frame:* If a dystopian government has that kind of RFID infrastructure in place, won't they have lists of all legal guns and confiscate them at need?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take.
"In a dystopian setting, implanted RFID tags would be used to track the whereabouts of civilians and to control what they can and can't do. The government could disable the RFID tag in a certain individual preventing them from using their gun."

I have a reality problem with that. We know for a fact that many fascist regimes, and many democratic ones but yours are dystopian, handle this particular situation in just one singular way: **BAN GUNS!**

Honestly. Where I live I can't legally get a Swiss army knife or carry a multi tool or risk angering the government.

Dictatorships are insanely terrified of armed citizens and so they completely ban any guns even pistols or shotguns or double barrel shotguns or anything similar.

So there is a huge contraction with a how you set the government and the fact they allow people to legally own guns in the first place.

So no government that is even inclined to be like that would allow guns.

Now the other important point. People need to understand that in country A legally owning firearms, for whatever reason, could be seen as god given or a constitutional right while in country B that is never a right.

Certain first world countries have zero gun policies and even sometimes not all their police is armed. So you have to realize that the implicit assumption is people should have guns and that is not universal.
And yes. The other way, they should never have guns, is not universal either.

Lastly an important point in actual external or 3rd party or similar limitations.

Here is an interesting thing about that. If you allow enough legal weapons to exist in the market then you will allow enough illegal weapons to also exist in the market. It's as basic as the company/story/person reporting 1 of every 50 guns as destroyed or nonoperational or whatever.

Now this means that even if you manage to produce a 100% working thing like you want. That only means that in the market many many illegal gunsmiths and stores will make unrestricted guns.

Lastly I'm sure that 99% of people that like or use or familiar with guns will 100% object to the idea. Guns are awesome. They are just a thing of engineering with a bit of chemistry and that's it. That is why they are very reliable and popular.
However once you add complicated electronics the reliably goes downhill real quick.
I mean even today certain people prefer a revolver to a semi-automatic pistol just for that exact reason. Even if it's an added 0.4 chance of not having a jam or something similar.

When it comes to saving your life and defending yourself people won't trust something that may not function because they forgot to change the battery or because their radio was loud or because they were microwaving a slice of pizza the day before or anything similar. Even the idea is enough. I just say something similar about the AR-15 forward assist. The army insisted that merely having the thing is batter and I recommend seeing [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHSSO-vJTSs).
This is honestly against what I know, so it might not be universal, about firearms and their philosophy.

Now this is just what comes to mind as a "problem" in the premise with the provided information. I'm not saying it's wrong or anything. So maybe you did fix those problems, say an insanely reliable device, or have very strong reasons for doing that. Just make sure to mention them in the story or at least make it clear to people.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is not to *disable* the gun selectively but rather to *enable* it for certain users. The access can of course be revoked, so you effectively have a way to lock the gun for a person. In terms of system security, every resource must have least amount of access allowed to unknown user. Once the user is identified, access to additonal functions of system is enabled. If it were built the other way around, the users would only need to stay anonymous in order to gain access (prevent the system from recognizing them and thus not applying restrictions).

What I'm trying to emphasize is that gun will not be recognizing people in order to block them. Rather it will unlock itself only for identified users. In all other cases it will remain locked. End result is about the same but it is important distinction to look at security this way.

Having the reader in the gun and the RFID tag attached to the user (implanted if you wish) is certainly OK. The gun must however be part of reliable security infrastructure that maintains access rules to its users and resources. The wireless link to central authority may fail but at least intermittent connection is needed in order to update the gun security settings.

In civilian application the authorization would work in similar manner as accessing your laptop that is part of network domain. The user is validated against cached profile when the wifi is not working, so you can still fire (or use text editor). The domain administrator can change users access rights even when they are offline, the rules apply to local resource (eg file folders in the laptop) at the next update.

About the OP remark about the lack of space in guns, I think that is the least of problems. There is lots of room in the frame of assault rifle and even pistols could accomodate extra module with some redesign. Highly reliable electronic trigger blocker is somewhat problematic at the current level of tech, it must be more shockproof than the smart phone, but not impossible to do.

The biggest obstacle to the access restricted guns is the lack of will to implement them. Prototypes so far have not been too great either. Still, nobody is thinking we should remove the access control from phones and computers.

As a side note, I dont think the electronic access control for guns is something dystopian. I'm of course from the country where gun availability is severly limited.

Answer (score 1):

**combination lock bullets**

The question has two parts *Tracking guns* and *stoping people from Shooting guns*

**Tracking**

Tracking is simple, every second a small interior cpu that is integrated to the electric firing pin sends the position of the gun to a local data center. The firing pin must be handled by a Government Official, and if your gun doesn't send a signal then the police know your last known location and will bring their tracked guns to your position. Don't worry citizen.

**Stopping people from shooting**

Your firing pin could be made to be more complex than normal. Basically, the gun is a key and your bullet is a lock. You could make the firing pin automatically align the bullet to the right direction with a magnet and then pulse the bullet in specific sections of the back plate, like entering a combination on a lock. The bullet would then only be shot if the right combination of shocks are administered to the sections of the back plate, like a lock. The bullet would have a constantly changing circuit that is determined by a hash function and a miniature atomic clock which will change the circuit of the lock every minute.

Mathematically you could say it looks like this

*this minute's combination = hash(type of bullet you are firing+minutes since Jan 1 2000)*

This means that in order to have your gun be able to "unlock" your bullets you need to know this minute's combination, and in order to get that you need to be connected to the network and the network has to send you the combination. The hash function will make it computationally impossible to guess the next combination, but the government will have the resources to compute it and send it out to the users. Furthermore, the Government might make it harder by having bullets be of a specific type 1 through 100 so even if you do manage to crack the code then you can only fire 1% of bullets. This does mean there will be plenty of jammed bullets for civilian guns due to manufacturing problems. however, this means that the bullets should be able to be locked by not telling users the right combination.